# How do I fix the bug on DatePicker and TimePicker when details are not correctly recorded in MongoDB with MERN Stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, datetimepicker, mern

Bug on DatePicker and TimePicker on MERN Stack

Hello!
I am facing an issue... When I book appointment, the details are sent. The information is showing up in mongoDB.

Everything is getting recorded but the timings and dates are not getting recorded correctly.

Whatever time & date I enter on the booking page of that doctor, the mongoDB only records time as 00:00 and date as current date.
Can you help me please??

The client code:

```
function BookAppoiment() {
    const [esteDisponibil, setEsteDisponibil] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [date, setDate] = useState();
    const [ora, setOra] = useState();
    const params = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [doctor, setDoctor] = useState(null);
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

    const getDoctorData = async () => {
        try {
            dispatch(showLoading());
            const response = await axios.post(
                '/api/doctor/get-doctor-info-by-id',
                { doctorId: params.doctorId },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                    },
                }
            );
            dispatch(hideLoading());
            if (response.data.success) {
                setDoctor(response.data.data);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            dispatch(hideLoading());
        }
    };

    const checkAvailability = async () => {
        if (date && ora) {
            try {
                dispatch(showLoading());
                const response = await axios.post(
                    '/api/user/check-booking-availability',
                    {
                        doctorId: params.doctorId,
                        date: date,
                        ora: ora,
                    },
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                        },
                    }
                );
                dispatch(hideLoading());
                if (response.data.success) {
                    toast.success(response.data.message);
                    setEsteDisponibil(true);
                } else {
                    toast.error(response.data.message);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error('Ceva nu a mers bine la verificarea disponibilității!');
                dispatch(hideLoading());
            }
        }
    };



    const bookNow = async () => {
        setEsteDisponibil(false);
        try {
            dispatch(showLoading());
            const response = await axios.post(
                '/api/user/book-appointment',
                {
                    doctorId: params.doctorId,
                    userId: user._id,
                    doctorInfo: doctor,
                    userInfo: user,
                    date: date,
                    ora: ora,
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                    },
                }
            );
            dispatch(hideLoading());
            if (response.data.success) {
                toast.success(response.data.message);
                navigate('/appointments');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error('Ceva nu a mers bine la crearea programării!');
            dispatch(hideLoading());
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getDoctorData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Layout>
            {doctor && (
                <div>
                    <h1 className="page-title">
                        {doctor.numeDoctor} {doctor.prenumeDoctor}
                    </h1>
                    <hr />
                    <Row gutter={20} className="mt-5" align="middle">
                        <Col span={12} sm={24} xs={24} lg={8}>
                            <h1 className="normal-text">
                                <b>Ore de lucru medic ales: </b>
                                {doctor.oreLucru[0]} - {doctor.oreLucru[1]}
                            </h1>
                            <div className="d-flex flex-column pt-2 mt-2">
                                {/* <DatePicker
                                    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                                    onChange={(value) => {
                                        setDate(moment(value).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
                                        setEsteDisponibil(false);
                                    }}
                                />

                                <TimePicker
                                    format="HH:mm"
                                    className="mt-3"
                                    onChange={(value) => {
                                        setEsteDisponibil(false);
                                        setOra(moment(value).format("HH:mm"));
                                    }}
                                /> */}
                                <DatePicker
                                    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                                    onChange={(value) => {
                                        const formattedDate = value ? moment(value).format("DD-MM-YYYY") : null;
                                        setDate(formattedDate);
                                        setEsteDisponibil(false);
                                    }}
                                />

                                <TimePicker
                                    format="HH:mm"
                                    className="mt-3"
                                    onChange={(value) => {
                                        const formattedTime = value ? moment(value).format("HH:mm") : null;
                                        setOra(formattedTime);
                                        setEsteDisponibil(false);
                                    }}
                                />


                                {!esteDisponibil && (
                                    <Button
                                        className="butonPrincipal mt-3 full-width-buton"
                                        onClick={checkAvailability}
                                    >
                                        Verifică disponibilitatea
                                    </Button>
                                )}
                                {esteDisponibil && (
                                    <Button
                                        className="butonPrincipal mt-3 full-width-buton"
                                        onClick={bookNow}
                                    >
                                        Programează-te
                                    </Button>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </div>
            )}
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default BookAppoiment;
```

The server code:

```
router.post('/book-appointment', authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        req.body.status = "pending";
        req.body.date = moment(req.body.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        req.body.ora = moment(req.body.ora, 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm:ss');
        const newAppointment = new Appointment(req.body);
        await newAppointment.save();

        // Send notifications to the doctor based on their userId
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.doctorInfo.userId });
        user.unseenNot.push({
            type: "new-appointment-request",
            message: `Pacientul ${req.body.userInfo.nume} ${req.body.userInfo.prenume} a făcut o nouă cerere de programare`,
            onClickPath: '/doctor/appointments',
        });
        await user.save();

        res.status(200).send({
            message: "Programare făcută cu succes!",
            success: true,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Eroare la crearea programarii",
            success: false,
            error,
        });
    }
});

router.post('/check-booking-availability', authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const date = moment(req.body.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').toISOString();

        const fromTime = moment(req.body.ora, "HH:mm").subtract(1, 'hours').toISOString();
        const toTime = moment(req.body.ora, "HH:mm").add(1, 'hours').toISOString();
        const doctorId = req.body.doctorId;

        const appointments = await Appointment.find({
            doctorId,
            date,
            ora: { $gte: fromTime, $lte: toTime },
        });

        if (appointments.length > 0) {
            return res.status(200).send({
                message: "Doctorul nu este disponibil pentru acea oră!",
                success: false,
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send({
                message: "Doctorul este disponibil pentru acea oră!",
                success: true,
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Eroare la verificarea disponibilității programării!",
            success: false,
            error,
        });
    }
});
```